# what the difference between layout and viewGroup in android

Tags: android

I already searched on internet about the difference between layout and view Group in android, but i didn't found an answer for this question, can any one tell me what is the difference between them and what is view Group uses, i already know layout use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A View Group is a subclass of the View class. It is a container that holds views such as ImageView, TextView, etc. Layouts are View Groups that are defined either by an xml file, or programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Layout is a xml file (or programmatically created) that encompasses multiple views to create a UI.

View Group is what you use to create your layout such as LinearLayout, RelativeLayout ConstraintLayout etc. These hold child views and their positions

Comment: you mean the screen or the app screen?

Comment: What does that even mean the screen or app screen

Comment: I mean the container of app in other word app screen